# How to test an object class inherit from a certain abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

In Python when you want to test that an object `foo` is an instance of `Foo` you do this :

```
if isinstance(foo, Foo):
    # do something
```

Now, imagine that `Foo` class is a specialized class inherited from `Bar` and that there is a lot of other classes that inherit from it: I've `Foo1`, `Foo2`, `...`, `FooX`, that inherit from `Bar` class.

`foo` could be an instance from any of these `Foox` class. What's interest me is to know that `foo` come from a class that inherited one day from `Bar`. Did you know a simple / canonical way to do it ?

Comment: Does what you wrote right there not work? If I'm understanding your question correctly then it sounds like you've already got your solution.

Comment: I'm not clear enough I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is probably to test if `foo` is a `Bar` object, which shows that `Foo` inherited from `Bar`.

```
class Bar:
    pass

class Foo(Bar):
    pass

foo = Foo()

isinstance(foo, Bar)
```

#### output:

```
True
```

You could also check if the class `Foo` is a subclass of the class `Bar`:

```
issubclass(Foo, Bar)   # notice Foo, the class, not the instance foo
```

Comment: Simpler that what I thought : )